# How do I reference the "title" given the id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var data = {};
data.event = [
{
    "id":"998",
    "title":"Foo",
    "thumb":"",
    "source":""
},
{
    "id":"999",
    "title":"Bar",
    "thumb":"",
    "source":""
}
]
```

Given that id=998 I need to extract the value of the "title" and I'm a bit lost as to the proper syntax.

Comment: What have you tried? It's an array of objects, so loop over each one and check if it has id=998. If it does, get that object's title attribute.

Comment: Well it's like this. I have no idea what I'm doing. Inherited an app jammed with ajax and json and callbacks...oh my. Doing ok so far but only by sheer hackery. I'm still picking up the lingo. I absolutely get that approach and am just lacking the syntax. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate with [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and check to see if the ID matches, and then write the value of title to a variable.

```
var title;

$.each(data.event, function(i,e) {
    if (this.id==='998') {
        title=this.title;
        return false;
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cxdPK/3/)

Comment: Not bailing from the loop when found = suboptimal

Comment: Bazinga!! Thanks a ton. New to js and the app I'm working on. You just saved a few hairs :-)

Comment: The return false does that already, but it was'nt there when I initially posted, hence the comment from ErikE.

Comment: You could extend this so that the `each` loop is in a function, and the function takes the id parameter. You then compare using `if(this.id==passedID) {...}`. I've never quite got the difference between `==` and `===` (never been interested enough to look into it, its not that I can't get my head around it) but I reckon you could use `===` with `passedID.toString()`, assuming `passedID` is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

```
function titleFromId(id) {
   for (var i = 0, l = data.event.length; i < l; i += 1) {
      if (data.event[i].id === id) {
         return data.event[i].title;
      }
   }
}

var title = titleFromId('998');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop over the `event` array.  For each item, if `item.id` is the value you are looking for, then return `item.title`.

Something like the following:

```
function findTitleById(desiredId) {
    var title, item;
    for (var i = data.event.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        item = data.event[i];
        if (item.id === desiredId) {
           title = item.title;
           break;
        }
    }
    return title;
}
```

There are more advanced ways to do this, but I would understand the above before attempting them.

Comment: I grok that and looping occurred to me...new to Javascript and the app in question so I was mainly lacking conviction...and syntax :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$.each()` function:

```
$.each(data.event, function(i, v){
    alert(v.id + " " + v.title)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NGALP/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, just alerts every value in the array...!?!

Comment: @ErikE yes, your function handles it well +1.